# The change in the UI made the firebug to select the standard.css instead of the original style

Tags: css, gwt, firebug

I have written the following css

```
 .rightCheckBoxes {
      float: right;
      width: 139px;
      margin: 4px 3px 2px 3px;
 }



 <div class="clearfix">
    <g:HTML addStyleNames="{style.formLabel}" ui:field="accountHTMLLabel">A<u>c</u>count</g:HTML>
    <fa:FocusAwareSuggestBox maxLength="20" addStyleNames="{style.formField} {style.accountWidth}" ui:field="accountSuggestBox"/>
    <g:Button addStyleNames="{style.normalButtons} {style.rightAlignment} {style.rightFieldAdjust}" enabled="false" ui:field="allocationButton">Bu<u>tto</u>n</g:Button>
    <g:CheckBox addStyleNames="{style.rightCheckBoxes}" checked="true" ui:field="allocationCompleteCB">Allocation Complete</g:CheckBox>
</div>
```

when  I change it to the following :

```
 .rightCheckBoxes {
      float: right;
      width: 139px;
      margin: 4px 3px 2px 3px;
 }

 <!-- Added this -->
.rightCheckBoxWidth {
      width:142px !important;            
 }  
 <!-- -->

<div class="clearfix">
    <g:HTML addStyleNames="{style.formLabel}" ui:field="accountHTMLLabel">T<u>i</u>tle</g:HTML>
    <fa:FocusAwareSuggestBox maxLength="20" addStyleNames="{style.formField} {style.accountWidth}" ui:field="acctSuggestBox"/>
    <g:Button addStyleNames="{style.normalButtons} {style.rightAlignment} {style.rightFieldAdjust}" enabled="false" ui:field="button1">Bu<u>tto</u>n</g:Button>
    <g:CheckBox addStyleNames="{style.rightCheckBoxes} {style.rightCheckBoxWidth}" checked="true" ui:field="chk2">Status Complete</g:CheckBox>
</div>
```

and click on the firebug option to view the element "chk2" it shows me the default style of the gwt checkbox element from the standard.css instead of picking up my own style above .Why is this I cannot understand logically!

Comment: You should edit your question to include what you changed. There are 700 characters in each code block. It is very difficult to discern what changes you made. Also, posting the rendered HTML is more useful than posting the `g` tags. We don't know how that stuff is getting translated.

Comment: Reduce the code snippets and simulate the bug with only checkbox.